# Laravel's updateOrCreate function

Tags: php, laravel-5.5

I have such table `| user_id | code | created_at | updated_at |`.

I want to create a method, which creates a new one code (if it not exists) for specific user:

```
public function createCode(Request $request)
{
    $request->user()->confirmationCode()->updateOrCreate([
        'user_id' => $request->user()->id,
        'code' => bin2hex(random_bytes(3)),
    ]);
}
```

`User` model:

```
public function confirmationCode()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(ConfirmationCode::class);
    }
```

But `createCode()` always creates a new one code for user, even code for that `user_id` is already exists. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax for updateOrCreate is incorrect. Currently to update it must match both of your inputs. You want the following:

```
public function createCode(Request $request)
{
    $request->user()->confirmationCode()->updateOrCreate(
        ['user_id' => $request->user()->id],
        ['code' => bin2hex(random_bytes(3))]
    );
}
```

The function matches on the first input array and then if found Updates with the values in the second array. If the matching fails it will create a new record with the values from both arrays.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#other-creation-methods